# Subset a dataframe based on numerical values of a string inside a variable

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, subset, as.date

I have a data frame which is a time series of meteorological measurement with monthly resolution from 1961 till 2018. I am interested in the variable that measures the monthly average temperature since I need the multi-annual average temperature for the summers.

To do this I must filter from the "DateVaraible" column the fifth and sixth digit, which are the month.
The values in time column are formatted like this
"19610701". So I need the 07(Juli) after 1961.

I start coding for 1 month for other purposes, so I did not try anything worth to mention. I guess that .grepl could do the work, but I do not know how the "matching" operator works.

So I started with this code that works.

```
summersmonth<- Df[DateVariable %like% "19610101" I DateVariable %like% "19610201"]
```

I am expecting a code like this

```
summermonths <- Df[DateVariable %like% "**06**" I DateVariable%like% "**07**..]
```

So that all entries with month digit from 06 to 09 are saved in the new dataframe summermonths.

Thanks in advance for any reply or feedback regarding my question.

**Update**

Thank to your answers I got the first part, which is to convert the variable in a `as.date` with the format "month"(Class=char)
Now I need to select months from Juni to September .
A horrible way to get the result I wanted is to do several `subset` and a `rbind` afterward.

```
Sommer1<-subset(Df, MonthVar == "Mai")
Sommer2<-subset(Df, MonthVar == "Juli")
Sommer3<-subset(Df, MonthVar == "September")

SummerTotal<-rbind(Sommer1,Sommer2,Sommer3)
```

I would be very glad to see this written in a tidy way.

**Update 2 - Solution**

Here is the tidy way, as here [Using multiple criteria in subset function and logical operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794414/using-multiple-criteria-in-subset-function-and-logical-operators)

```
Veg_Seas<-subset(Df, subset = MonthVar %in% c("Mai","Juni","Juli","August","September"))
```

Comment: If `DateVariable` always follows the format: "YYYYMMDD", you could use `substr`: `summermonths <- Df[substr(DateVariable, 6, 6) %in% 6:9, ]`

Comment: re your edit, is `Mean_Temp$MESS_DATUM_BEGINN` the result of `month` function on your date variable (converted into date)?

Comment: Yes, Mean_Temp$MESS_DATUM_BEGINN is the result of the function.(allmonths)
I first tried your function but it didnt work beacuse of the missing **s** in `month`, therefore I used `as.Date` withouth `month` which gave me a result in this format _1961-01-01_.
Today I tried again your function with `months`.
The result is a character class with the name of the month.

Now I would like to know how to subset them, either as char. or num. value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert your date variable as date (format) and take the month:

```
allmonths <- month(as.Date(Df$DateVariable, format="%Y%m%d"))
```

*Note that of your column has been originally imported as `factor` you need to convert it to `character` first:*

```
allmonths <- month(as.Date(as.character(Df$DateVariable), format="%Y%m%d"))
```

Then you can check whether it is a summermonth:

```
summersmonth <- Df[allmonths %in% 6:9, ]
```

**Example:**

```
as.Date("20190702", format="%Y%m%d")
[1] "2019-07-02"

month(as.Date("20190702", format="%Y%m%d"))
[1] 7
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the first line of your code(conversion to as.Date) and I got this message:
  "Error in as.Date.numeric(Mean_Temp$MESS_DATUM_BEGINN, format = "%Y%m%d") : 
  'origin' must be supplied ".

Comment: @m_rub please give the result of `dput(head(Mean_Temp$MESS_DATUM_BEGINN))` : without further details it's hard to know what causes the error. It's very likely that you are dealing with `factors` and not `characters`, then passing the same line with `allmonths <- month(as.Date(as.character(Df$DateVariable), format="%Y%m%d"))` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

We can use `anydate` from `anytime` to convert to `Date` class and then extract the `month`

```
library(anytime)
month(anydate(as.character(Df$DateVariable)))
```

Comment: @m_rub May be you have numeric values.  Convert to `character` and try.  I updated the post

Comment: True, as I found out here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315463/how-to-determine-the-correct-argument-for-origin-in-as-date-r 

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I appreciate you help and I am willing to give you the credit, but my initial question was more about how to filter/subset some month, than how to change format. I guess change format could be the first step to get my problem solved, but the problem itself is still unsolved.